# How do I add timestamp to Cognos 11 file written to share folder

Tags: cognos-11

I have a file that is written by Cognos 11 to a shared folder.  Problem is that each time Cognos writes the file, it uses the exact same file name.  Subsequent outputs fail if the file name already exists.  So, I need something line a timestamp added to the name to uniquely identify the file.

There are 2 setting2 for email attachments to set up  the file name with a timestamp.  These are emf.dls.attachment.timestamp.enabled and emf.dls.attachment.timestamp.format.  They do not affect a file name that is written to a network folder.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you selected "Time stamp" under the delivery options ?

[image]

Comment: I did not know about this.  Thanks.  I tried it, and it does what I need.  Very grateful for the answer.

Comment: No worries mate !